# Tensorflow debug or print statements

Tags: debugging, printing, tensorflow

I am very new to TensorFlow and trying to learn it. I copied a program from tutorial website. As I modified it, there are issues with the program and I have to debug. I am looking for help to understand how I can print certain values such as cost and optimizer. I have to figure out to see the value being updated in each iteration. I understand that notes cannot be printed but I take that cost and optimizers are inputs which should be printable, right?

```
plt.ion()
n_observations = 100
xs = np.linspace(-3, 3, n_observations)
ys = np.sin(xs) + np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5, n_observations)

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

Y_pred = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]), name='bias')
for pow_i in range(1, 5):

    W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]), name='weight_%d' % pow_i)
    Y_pred = tf.add(tf.multiply(tf.pow(X, pow_i), W), Y_pred)

cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(Y_pred - Y, 2)) / (n_observations - 1)
d = tf.Print(cost, [cost, 2.0], message="Value of cost id:")

learning_rate = 0.01
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

n_epochs = 10
with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    prev_training_cost = 0.0
    for epoch_i in range(n_epochs):


    for (x, y) in zip(xs, ys):
    print("Msg2 x, y ", x, y, cost);
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})
    sess.run(d)
    print("Msg3 x, y ttt ", x, y, optimizer);

        training_cost = sess.run(
            cost, feed_dict={X: xs, Y: ys})
        print(training_cost)
        print("Msg3 cost, xs ys", cost, xs, ys);

        if epoch_i % 100 == 0:
            ax.plot(xs, Y_pred.eval(
                feed_dict={X: xs}, session=sess),
                'k', alpha=epoch_i / n_epochs)
        fig.show()
        #plt.draw()
    # Allow the training to quit if we've reached a minimum
    if np.abs(prev_training_cost - training_cost) < 0.001:
        break
    prev_training_cost = training_cost

ax.set_ylim([-3, 3])
fig.show()
plt.waitforbuttonpress()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `cost` and `optimizer` refer to tensors in the graph, not inputs to your graph. The need to be fetched in a `session.run` call to be able to print their python values. For example, in your example, printing `training_cost` should be printing the cost. Similarly, if you return the value you of `optimizer` from `session.run(optimizer, ...)`, it should return the correct printable value.

If you are interested in debugging and printing values check out:

- [tfdbg](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/debugger)
- [tf.Print](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print)

Hope that helps!